# Power Bi - function count returns value 1

Tags: count, dax, rows, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Hello my good friends,

I would like to have your help to something very simple I think.
I am working with PBi and I tried the function COUNT.
I am trying to count the rows of a table that have only numbers.
Data type of column is Whole Number.
I uses the following function :  ***zOrdersCounter = COUNTA(REPORT[Document   ])***
I add a card and I get 1 instead of having as a result 70.
What am I doing wrong ?

I just noticed that it counts **only** the first line of the table. Same story with function SUM. Could you please help ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: From what you are showing us this is not reproducible.

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. what do you mean ? I tried the same with function sum and it returns the number of the first cell of the column. It doesn't sum the whole column. Any idea ?  As you can understand I am new user to power bi.

Comment: I think it interacts with the selected lines. So I do not think this is a problem...

Comment: What do you mean with "selected lines"? Where's the sample data? Your composed picture doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You apply COUNT() not to a table, but column. When you get a result for one row it can be that something filters `REPORT` by other columns values with filters, slicers, matrix row value  or other dependecies. To count how many nonblank rows you have in `REPORT[Document]` independently of your context, you can try a followihg syntax:

```
zOrdersCounter = 
    COUNTX(
        ALL(REPORT)
       ,REPORT[Document]
    )
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to apply COUNT() or COUNTA() to a column.

Comment: @Peter, it's perfectly, when you want to count in a context.

Comment: And DAX is all about evaluation context.

Comment: @Peter my answer is about issue

Comment: The issue is that people are not aware of the fact that a single DAX formula can lead to 1000 different results - depending on the evaluation context. And then they are showing us meaningless screenshots, because they don't even realize that the evaluation context matters. Maybe your formula solves Zounds issue - who knows - but does it help in understanding the mechanics?

Comment: @Peter, yes, it's truth.